# Build a webpage/SharePoint page where users can add/remove themselves from O365 groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am asked to build a self service application on SharePoint where users can search through list of Publically accessible O365 groups. All users should be able to Add and Remove themselves from any specific group.

I planning to use Graph API for this.

Can anyone please provide some documentation or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following steps to build your above application:

- Register an Azure AD application and define an [auth workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios) which suits your scenario
- Make a call from the app to [AAD using library like MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview), get a valid access token
- Using the valid token, i will call to access the [protected resource like Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-graph-intro) with necessary roles/permissions defined.
- In your scenario, you will access the Microsoft Groups - then i will refer the [Graph API documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0).
- Implement your business logic to add/remove uses from the Group.
- You're good to go!!

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at the documentations and examples by going through this documentation : [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)

Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources.

After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

It has various features that it supports  : [Major Services in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview-major-services)